# video gallery with fancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to create a video gallery on a web page.

I have opted for **fancyBox**. i have gotten it to work. i however have two problems.

**First:**
I want the first video in the listing to show up as soon as the page renders.

**Second:**
I do not want the vidoe's to autmotically start. i want users to manualy start them.

This is the working code on fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/Xh3B2/

e.g see the image below

[image]

At the moment however,you need to click a link before the first video shows on the page. i.e

**My Code;**

Video #1

Video #2

```
function videoFancyBox()  {                     
    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none',
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            padding     : 0,
            margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin
        });
 }
```

**UPDATE:** 
JFK has kindly answered question one; i simply needed to place this at the end of hte code: .eq(0).click();

However, i am still having trouble with the auto start of the videos; i changed one of the params in the link to

```
 autoplay= 0;
```

However the video is still running once loaded

```
<a class="fancybox_video fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=0&enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque">Video #1</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fir the first question, just add `.eq(0).click()` at the end of your fancybox initialization script like

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        // API options
    })
    .eq(0).click();
```

The method `.eq(0)` targets the first (index `0`) selector `.fancybox` and the method `.click()` triggers a programmatic *click* on it after the page loads.

For the second question, just change the trailing parameter `autoplay` to `0` as suggested by [@user10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3863893/user10)

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Comment: Hello JFK. Thank you so much for your help. The .eq(0).click(); worked. thank you. however the autoplay 0 did not work. the vidoe still load. i have amended my question to show that its still automotically loading

Comment: sorry. i stand corrected. i just noticed your jsfiddle. thanks so much. it works perfeclty

Answer (score 0):

Video player automatically start to disable  to change **autoplay=1** to **autoplay=0** ...

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=0&wmode=opaque
```

Comment: Hi user10 i wll have a look at that. thanks. but do you know the answer to question i.e  first video in the listing to show up as soon as the page renders.

Comment: use this code to you get any idea:  iframe :{
            preload : false
        }  .. but i dont know this is 100% correct ...